# Which side of my cube is hitting the plane below the cube

Tags: unity-game-engine, cube, raycasting

Im working in Unity and I have a simple scene. It consists of a cube which has a box collider on it. Below this cube is a plane
I want to know which side of the cube is hitting the plane at any given instant
One way to do this is to cast a ray from each side of the cube and determine which ray is colliding with the plane
But i fear that it may be performance heavy. Is there a way to do this in an efficient manner?

Comment: Raycasting is a really basic mathematical equation not involving any expensive computation (sqrt, trig or other recursive process). So if you are comfortable with raycast, just use it. You'll need a lot of raycasting to see a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I used for same need:
1) Place plane for each side of cude;
2) Set clear color for planes;
3) Write script that check plane position (in your option need loop that search plane with lower position.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a way other than just ray casting then you could create a method that takes in your cube's position and your plane's position and then do some calculations.

```
Vector3 heading = plane.transform.position - cube.transform.position;
float distance = heading.magnitude;
Vector3 direction = heading / distance;
```

From here you would just have to check what that direction is.